# mix WebMvcConfigurerAdapter with xml based <mvc:resources/> configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can I use the following configuration simultaneously?

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/, classpath:/static/"/>
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ResourceMappingsAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/anotherStatic/", "file:///...");
}
```

The mapping added from the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter doesn't seem to serve the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I figured this out. The order seems to matter. Adjusting the

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" order="1"/>
```

and

```
registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

in the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter solved the issue.

Comment: where did you put the file containing `<mvc:resource` ? And how did you write code to use it ?